# AWS signedURL with AWS Transfer Acceleration using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

How Can I use boto 3 to generate a accelerated transfer signedURL?

I can generate a standard signedURL by

```py
client = boto3.client('s3')
parameters = {
      'Bucket' : bucket,
      'Key' : key
}
signed_url = client.generate_presigned_url(
      'get_object',
      Params = parameters,
      ExpiresIn = 300000
)
```

But I can't find anywhere in the amazon boto3 [document](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) if there is an option to use an accelerated endpoint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass it on the client config like follows:

```py
 client = boto3.client(
     's3',
     config = botocore.client.Config(
         s3 = {
             'use_accelerate_endpoint': True
         }
     ) 
 )
```